# Run RabbitMQ server in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, rabbitmq

I'm getting an EOFException when connecting to the vanilla RabbitMQ Docker container. The log directory is empty /var/log/rabbitmq contains no files. The web console works without problems. It's just connecting to it that doesn't work.

Since this is the vanilla container from the Docker Hub, I presume it's me omitting something basic. But what ? :-)

Is there something else I can check ?

---

The command to create the container:

```
sudo docker run -d --hostname konijn --name konijn -p 5672:5762 -p 5671:5671 -p 15672:15672 rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
```

It shows up as running:

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                NAMES
0a62c2635d17        rabbitmq:3.6.6-management   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   12 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       4369/tcp, 5672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5671->5671/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->5762/tcp   konijn
```

When running this code sample:

```
  @Test
  public void testUnprotectedConnection() throws Exception {
    final ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setUri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/");
    Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
  }
```

I'm getting:

```
java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:353)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
    at com.enervalis.messaging.rabbitmq.RabbitMQCertificateTest.testUnprotectedConnection(RabbitMQCertificateTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:372)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:297)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571)
    ... 1 more
```

The container's log files are missing:

```
$ sudo docker exec konijn ls -l /var/log/rabbitmq
total 0
```

The docker version information:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 10:05:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 10:05:19 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

System information:

```
XUbuntu 16.10, amd64

$ uname -a
Linux black 4.8.0-34-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 21 17:24:18 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 16.10
```

Comment: You are exposing `5672:5762` ports. Inner port of container is  5**7**62, but RabbitMq default port is 5**6**72. May be this problem?

Comment: ... I stand corrected ... it was the port indeed ! Damn that's embarrassing ! Set it as an answer. I'll mark it as being the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exposing `5672:5762` ports. Inner port of container is 5**7**62, but RabbitMQ default port is 5**6**72.